# how to create a shared folder on Virtual machine

Tags: solaris, virtualbox

We have a windows Oracle vm installed on our solaris machine which will be launched using Xmanager.

Can some one please help me with the following questions

I can use the folders on solaris from windows VM using "\vboxsrv" but how can i do viceversa
How can i access files on windows vm from solaris machine

And can i update the files on windows vm directly without opening it through xmanager

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to execute a command on virtual machine from Hostmachine. Using this command tool I am accessing files or folders in virtual machine

The command line tool is VBoxManage - This has lot of parameters using we can do any thing on virtual machine from VM starting to shutdown

/opt/VirtualBox > VBoxManage Startvm "windows"
/opt/VirtualBox > VBoxManage guestcontrol "windows" execute --image "cmd.exe" --username root --password 12345 --wait-exit --wait-stdout -- -l /usr